# How do I capitalize each parameter in a function definition using Python?

Tags: python, regex

If functions look like:
    `function example(parameter1 : p1; parameter2 : p2);`

How do I capitalize the first letter of each parameter name?

The output should be:
    `function example(Parameter1 : p1; Parameter2: p2);`

Thanks!

Comment: Use your IDE's refactor feature. Otherwise you'll break your code.

Comment: @DeepSpace, why would this break my code? I'm just thinking pattern matching using regexes or something of the sort.

Comment: x0xchoc0late: How will regexes solve your problem? Can you give an example? Unless you are considering the function name and definition to be a string I don't think regexes would be of any help. As @DeepSpace mentioned refactoring will change the names wherever the function has been referenced in the workspace

Comment: @mad_ I'm running through each line of code in a file, considering them to be strings so that I can format them (basically the job of an IDE). My goal here is just to capitalize certain things, in this case - parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution could be using string slicing and `capitalize()` function

```
a='function example(parameter1 : p1; parameter2 : p2);'
temp=''
start_brace_index=a.index('(')
end_brance_index=a.index(')')

for i in a[start_brace_index+1:end_brance_index].split(';'):
    temp+=i.strip().capitalize()+', '
```

Then printing the results

```
print(a[:start_brace_index+1]+temp.rstrip(', ')+a[end_brance_index:])
```

**Output**

```
'function example(Parameter1 : p1, Parameter2 : p2);'
```